# In HighCharts, how can I make a bar in a bar chart a different color based on value?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If the y value is 1, I want the bar to be green. All other bars I want to be orange. Is there a way to do this? I don't know where the y value can be checked in order to assign a color to a bar.

Here is my code for charting the graph.

```js
HighCharts.chart(
    graph_element,
    {
        title: {
            text: ""
        },

        chart: {
            height: 250,
            type: 'column'
        },

        series: data,

        credits: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: { enabled: true },
        legend: {
            enabled: show_legend,
            align: 'center',
            width: '100%',
        },

        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                color: "#F18A00", //THIS IS THE ORANGE
            },
            column: {
                minPointLength: 3,
            },
            series: {
                pointStart: start_date_unix*1000,
                pointInterval: 24*60*60*1000,
                animation: false,
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            tickInterval: 24*60*60*1000,
            labels: {
                format: this.active_filter == "week" ? '{value:%a}' : '{value:%b %e}',
            },
            min: start_date_unix*1000,
            max: end_date_unix*1000
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 1,
            tickAmount: 9,
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `chart.events.load()` that allows you to add the condition updating `point.color` during loading the chart.

**Example code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this;
        chart.series.forEach(series => {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            if (point.y === 1) {
              point.update({
                color: 'green'
              })
            }
          })
        })
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    color: 'orange'
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2j1p4bs8/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update